# Send catched ajax exception back to server to perform logging?

Tags: ajax, exception, error-handling, elmah

i have an MVC3 application and i'm using Elmah to store the errors in a mysql database and even send those errors by email. This is working perfectly, now i have this javascript code in my main layout:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, settings, exception) {
   //SEND BACK TO SERVER THE EXCEPTION
});
```

Now, what i want to do is to get the catched exception (the ajax exception) and send back to server to a method that stores that exception with Elmah. Is that possible? If it isn't what choice do i have?

Answer (score 1):

This following article shows some good guidance on how to log JavaScript errors back to Elmah:

[Logging Errors with ELMAH in ASP.NET MVC 3 – Part 5 – (JavaScript)](http://joel.net/logging-errors-with-elmah-in-asp.net-mvc-3--part-5--javascript)

I know the mechanism to report the error to the server is specific to MVC, but it should be easily adaptable to ASP.NET Web Forms as well if needed.

Comment: This looks really nice, but something that i dont understand of this is if you need to try and catch to log the error on the js code? Because i have an entire project without try/catch's on my js code.. do i need to add it to the entire js code?

Comment: No, you do not need to add try/catch. The javascript stacktrace code adds a window.onerror handler that catches any unhandled errors. In the examples in the post, it shows both unhandled and handled (via try/catch) JavaScript errors being caught and logged to Elmah.

Comment: I cant believe it... yesterday the link was working perfectly and today it's broken.. LOL

Comment: Great! they have just fixed the link :D