# Trap message/exception in jquery to ELMAH

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, exception, elmah

In my MVC3 application, I am returning messages from my stored procs. If it is 'successful', I'm moving forward else displaying a custom error page.
When the message is something else, I want to trap it in ELMAH. The problem that I am facing is that the return message is not really an error so I'm not able to figure out how to handle it. I still want to display the custom error page after catching the error in ELMAH.
Please help.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../XYZ",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ abcData: abcData, strDeb: strDeb, strCre: strCre }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            if (logout != "Logout") {
                if (data.toLowerCase() != "successful") {
                    **//alert(data.toString());
                    window.location.href = "../Error";**
                } else {
                    window.location.href = "../ABC";
                }
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            var sessionWindowElement = $('#SessionLayoutLogOutWindow');
            sessionWindowElement.data('tWindow').center().open();
        }
    });
```

Comment: See previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530358/send-catched-ajax-exception-back-to-server-to-perform-logging

Comment: Found the solution here:
http://ivanz.com/2011/05/08/logging-javascript-errors-with-elmah/

Comment: Thanks @PaigeCook...that post set me on the right track!